# Can not read the property maps of undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

### Hi I am learning ionic 3, I am practicing to add maps in ionic application but I'm getting error

> Can not read property maps of undefined

---

```js
export class LocationsPage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapref : ElementRef;
map : any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.dispMap();
  }
 
  dispMap(){
  let coords = new google.maps.latlng('17.512511','78.352228');
  let mapoptions = { 
center : coords,
zoom : 14,
mapTypeId : google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapref.nativeElement,mapoptions);
}

}
```

```css
    #my-map{
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<ion-content>

<div #map id="my-map"></div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: `google.maps` can not find so this error occur have you define that anywhere ? You can refer this https://www.ghadeer.io/ionic-3-google-maps/ to implement google maps

Comment: Make sure you have added google api js in your application, if yes, add in bottom of the body tag

Comment: in index.html i mentioned the key above cordova script tag like   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIza"></script>

Comment: @johnny That is not going to work, you have to add https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis and import it in your Code.

Comment: please explain me what are the plugins i have to add